# Setting SKSpriteNode position by using invisible UIView in Storyboard

Tags: ios, uiview, sprite-kit, storyboard, skspritenode

I just recently started on iOS Spritekit. Most tutorials and StackOverflow topics mentioned that I can't use Storyboard for arranging SKSpriteNode so I've been struggling on layout my views, especially I also have some other components like UILabels. 
I hack this by placing invisible UIViews (and do autolayout on them with other components), and pass the values into the SKScene which will place SpriteNode based on the value--after converting the coordinate systems, etc. 
Would there be potential issues on this approach? It works for simple cases but it is obviously a hack... :P
 
Or if there are better way of layout SpriteNode? I am going through RayWenderlich tutorials, but so far many of them seems to be hardcoded positions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's certainly more work than needs to be done so there could be performance issues.  As an alternative (and the correct way) to do this is use the scene editor in Xcode.

Create a new SpriteKit Scene File and add your nodes to it.  Create a new Swift file of class SKScene and set the custom class for the scene file.

Then all you have to do to get those nodes into your class (like IBOutlet) is the following...

```
override func didMove(to: view){
    let shipNode = self.childNode(withName: "shipNodeName") as! SKSpriteNode

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Found a tutorial on it as well.